# IE Not Showing Page Margin

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, margin

I have just got a developer to redesign my website and I have noticed one thing.
In Google Chrome my web page has a nice margin around it, about 2". But on IE the page goes right up to the edge of the page and makes the page look super big.
I want them both to have a margin around the page.
The web page I am talking about is, [web design quotes](http://www.fourquotes.co.uk/webdesign).
Is the code I need to change in the CSS?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: looks the same to me in all browsers, what version of ie are you using?

Comment: do you use a ie version lower than 9?, it looks fine for me too. can you post your css code?

Comment: I am using IE 8, I am thinking that I might have been zoomed in on IE :0 I am going to do a cross browser test.

Answer (score 1):

This link will show you how to make 'responsive web designs' so it fits all resolutions.

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-responsive-web-design

---

You can try this. it helps you when it does not work in IE

```
body {
    margin:50px 0px; padding:0px;
    text-align:center;
    }

#Content {
    width:500px;
    margin:0px auto;
    text-align:left;
    padding:15px;
    border:1px dashed #333;
    background-color:#eee;
    }
```

in your body you give the margin and in your content you do an margin auto.

as explained here: http://bluerobot.com/web/css/center1.html

Comment: I have just used BrowserStacker to test it, it seems to be that the problem is with the screen resolution, on 1024x768 there is no margin regardless of browser, but on 1280x1024 there is a margin.

Comment: if you had something about my answer don't forget to accept it. if not it's your own choice

Comment: No not managed to fix it, just now know what the problem is. Does anyone know how to make a page display the same over all screen resolutions.

Comment: you just need to set the margin-right: auto; and margin-left: auto; that will fit it automatically. as i said in my answer.

Comment: @KeesSonnema - Looks like @­Derek is not going to accept your answer. :) Nonetheless I upvoted your answer.

Comment: Thanks. i hope you will have something about it.